# php explode new lines content from a txt file

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I have txt file with email addresses under under the other like :

```
test@test.com
test2@test.com
```

So far I managed to open it with

```
 $result = file_get_contents("tmp/emails.txt");
```

but I don't know to to get the email addresses in an array. Basically I could use explode but how do I delimit the new line ?
thanks  in advance for any answer !

Comment: The answers below are ideal; but for reference, you could use explode with the newline character, represented as \n. (This may also be \r\n depending on whether you're using Windows or Linux).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Just read the file using [`file()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) and you'll get an array containing each line of the file.

```
$emails = file('tmp/emails.txt');
```

To not append newlines to each email address, use the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag, and to skip empty lines, use the `FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES` flag:

```
$emails = file('tmp/emails.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
```

Doing a `var_dump($emails)` of the second example gives this:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "test@test.com"
  [1]=>
  string(14) "test2@test.com"
}
```

Comment: THough this works, it doesn't take into account windows based new lines. using preg_split works more reliably.

Answer (score 11):

```
$lines = preg_split('/\r\n|\n|\r/', trim(file_get_contents('file.txt')));
```

Answer (score 2):

As crazy as this seems, doing a `return` or `enter` inside a double-quote (`""`) delimits a newline. To make it clear, type in:

```
explode("", "Stuff to delimit");
```

and simply hit return at the middle of `""`, so you get:

```
explode("

", "stuff to delimit");
```

and it works. Probably unconventional, and might only work on Linux. But it works.